# best  web content books/websites/articles?

Tags: content, recommendations, books, writing

I was reading through "best web programming books" articles, and I saw the book [Content Strategy for the Web](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321620062) by Kristina Halvorson.

So, what is a similar (or better, please specify if it's better) book? Or maybe even a website/article...

Answer (score 1):

Not related to content strategy so much as how to write for the web, but *[Letting Go of the Words: Writing Web Content that Works](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123694868)* by Janice Redish (forward by Steve Krug) is pretty highly recommended. I haven't read the book you mentioned, so I dunno if it's better.

And I personally haven't read these, but a quick search on Amazon came up with these 2 titles with very high user review ratings:

- *[The Web Content Strategist's Bible: The Complete Guide to a New and
  Lucrative Career for Writers of All
  Kinds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441482628)* - Richard Sheffield
- *[The Yahoo! Style Guide: The Ultimate Sourcebook for Writing, Editing, and Creating Content for the Digital World](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/031256984X)* - Chris Barr